# Is there a way to develop Shopify Apps without using next.js (or at least without SSR)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify

Every documentation and examples I found for creating Shopify App involve Next.js and SSR, is there any way to use Polaris components and make authenticated requests, etc. without having to use Next.js or SSR ?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use any kind of back-end language with any kind of framework:

- nodejs
- php
- python
- ruby
  ..etc

Any backend language and framework that can communicate with REST Api can be used for apps.

Their documentation includes NextJS because that is their framework of choice for demos and guides, but you are not limited to that.

Comment: Yes in my search I saw a lot of answers like this but couldn't find any link to an example